# How to send android push notification from website chat

Tags: java, php, android, jquery

I have completed programming a website chat like whatsapp design and I have created application in android. The app browser this website chat (only show website like chrome browser).
I need help to understand how can I get notification on my application when user get message The android notification should show "you have new message".

My question is how I can send data from website to android using push notification

[The website chat](http://%20i.stack.imgur.com/TNP2r.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your android application should be GCM registered and then you can send a GCM from your website which will then be pushed to your application.

For more details see : https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

For detailed tutorial see : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: i need method , without using internet ? local connection

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function notificationToAndroidAction($pushId){

        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => array($pushId),
            'data' => array("message" => 'hello!'),
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarily
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        return 'sent';
    }
```

Comment: i ca't use google server , bcz i want my project work without variable internet  (local connection )?